# how do i append string to the beginning of a list?

Tags: python

I need help trying to append string to the beginning of a list.

I have the following:

```
stringlist = [a,b,c,d]
word = ("hey")
```

I want to append hey to the beginning of the list so that i get the following:

```
stringlist = [h,e,y,a,b,c,d]
```

I know that:

```
stringlist.append(word)
```

would append the word but at the end and not in the order i want it to append.

How would i do this without any built in functions?

Comment: By `a,b,c`, do you mean variables `a`, `b` and `c`? Or strings `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`?

Comment: strings "a","b","c", so that i would get "h","e","y","a","b","c","d" and the new length us 6.

Comment: @cosmicablzed new length should be 7.

Comment: i thought it counts from 0? so first letter is 0. at least it's what i have learned in class.

Answer (score 3):

This would work:

```
stringlist = ['a','b','c','d']
word = ("hey")
stringlist=list(word)+ stringlist
print(len(stringlist))
#7
```

Comment: this works however what would i do if i want to extend the length of the list. Basically this adds it where i want it but seperate from the rest, i want [h,e,y,a,b,c,d] so that the new length is now 6 but if i use this then my length is 4.

Comment: That is not true. Your length would be 7 as it is not adding a list to the list but it is just working as extend which adds element to the list. Please check it again!

Comment: alright i have tried i did:                                       list1 = ["a,b,c,d,e"]
word = ("hey")
'''list1=list(word)+ list1'''
list1 = [*word] + list1

print (list1)
print (len(list1))                                                         and my output is : ['h', 'e', 'y', 'a,b,c,d,e']
4

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
stringlist = [*word] + stringlist
```

Comment: thank you it works however not exactly how i need it, it gives me: ['h', 'e', 'y', 'a,b,c,d,e'] i want : [h,e,y,a,b,c,d,e']

Comment: [h, e, y, b, c, d, e] is a list of variables and only make sense if these (h, e, y, etc) are defined or do you want a list with one element like: ['h, e, y, a, b, c, d, e']? To do so you can first make the string 'h, e, y, a, b, c, d, e' by ','.join([*stringlist]) and then add this element to a list, or in one go: stringlist = [','.join([*stringlist])]